# translate animation from the where the last translate animation stopped

Tags: android, android-animation

I have a translate animation of an image from location1 to location2. However at any time during the animation, if a user click a button then I want to apply another translate animation from where the image at to location3 (even if the animation has not finished). Any way I can do that?

Thanks

```
TranslateAnimation translate = new TranslateAnimation(0, mDestLoc[0]-mSrcLoc[0], 0, mDestLoc[1]-mSrcLoc[1]);            
        translate.setFillAfter(true);
        translate.setDuration(getDuration());
        ball.startAnimation(translate);




void onbuttonClicked(){
// stop previous animation and translate image to location 3 "From where it stopped"

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why don't you use [ObjectAnimators](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/ObjectAnimator.html)?

You can create an animator for a particular target(or obtain the view one through [animate()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#animate%28%29) if you're running on a version greater-equal API level 12) and then translate, resize, fade,... your object.

If for some particular reasons the first animation is cancelled, you can call [cancel](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/ValueAnimator.html#cancel%28%29) and then the view will persist the current status. Then, if you create another animator based on the current values you should be able to easily perform another animation.